# How string variable in razor becomes the html element in java script

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've declared a simple string variable in razor page to store a dynamic id of a div.

```
 @{ 
     int i = 0;
     string divId = "Ratting_"+@i;
  }
```

and used it like

```
<div id="@divId">
   Test Div
 </div>
```

But when I'm accessing it in javascript like this

```
<script>
    var id = @divId;
    console.log(id);
</script>
```

It represent a html element instead of a string. I know if I put the `@divId` inside a `''` then will put string. But my question how this `@divId` just identified the html element. 
On browser console I'm getting this

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by 'identified the html element'? What do you see in the `Console.log()`?

Comment: In console.log it prints the html element

Comment: Got that from your code. But the question is what does it print in the console? Can you please add a screenshot of the output of console.log in the question?

Comment: var id = "@divId";. This would work

Comment: Hi I've added the snapshot. And my question is as I'm assigning a string in `@divId`.   But how does it represent the div element if I used it without `" "`